# How to get the last part of user agent?

Tags: python, parsing, user-agent

I want to get the last part of the user agent string, for example:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 Qlik

I want to get the last word, in this case, is Qlik, but it can be empty or with a longer word.

how can I do this in python?

Comment: Use: `re.findall(r'\w+$', user_agent)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

this maybe help you

```
a = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 Qlik'
a.split(' ')[-1]
## 'Qlik'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, what if it will be more than one word? I need all the words after 537.36 (which also can be different, and sometimes even not a number if it's IOS)

Comment: this works; a = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36 Qlik'; re.split(r'\w+\/[\w,\.]+',a);